# PreferenceFragment onPreferenceTreeClick not firing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a PreferenceFragment in my application.  It is displayed when selected from a ListFragment.  The class is pretty basic:

```
public class MyPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().setTitle("Preferences");
  }
}
```

It works great on a small device.  The problem occurs when I run on a tablet in landscape orientation.  If I click Preferences from the ListFragment on the left, MyPreferencesFragment is displayed on the right.  I can then select any preferences and change their values.  The problem occurs when I scroll the preferences list.  Once I do that, clicking any of the items in the preferences list does nothing.  I added:

```
@Override
public Boolean onPreferenceTreeClick (PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {

  System.out.println("preference " + preference.getKey() + " selected");
  return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
}
```

to see if that would shed any light on the situation.  It is called when things are working but once I scroll the list, it is no longer invoked.  Does anyone know what I need to do in order to be able to select a preference after scrolling?

Two more data points:

- It works fine in portrait orientation.
- If I click the power button to turn off the display (while the preferences list is displayed), when I turn the screen back on, I can select items even after scrolling. Re-selecting Preferences from the list at this point results in the original problem.

EDIT:

I commented that it works great on a small device but it appears to sometimes have the same issue with small devices.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was in one of the Preference classes I had created.  I extended the EditTextPreference class in order to make sure that the entered value was a number and in the appropriate range.  The original class looked like this:

```
public class NumberWithRangePreference extends EditTextPreference {

  private int min = -1;
  private int max = -1;
  private int defaultValue = -1;
  private int oldValue = -1;
  private String units = "";

  public NumberWithRangePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    for (int i=0; i<attrs.getAttributeCount(); ++i) {
      String attr = attrs.getAttributeName(i);

      if (attr.equals("min")) {
        min = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
      } else if (attr.equals("max")) {
        max = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
      } else if (attr.equals("units")) {
        units = attrs.getAttributeValue(i);
      } else if (attr.equals("defaultValue" )) {
        defaultValue = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
        oldValue = defaultValue;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup group) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(group);

    oldValue = Integer.parseInt(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString(getKey(), "" + defaultValue));
    setSummary(oldValue + " " + units);
    return view;
  }

  @Override 
  protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    oldValue = Integer.parseInt(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString(getKey(), "" + defaultValue));
    setSummary(oldValue + " " + units);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(getEditText().getEditableText().toString());
      if ((value < min) || (value > max)) {

        getEditText().setText("" + oldValue);

        AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        errorDialog.setTitle("Invalid Entry");
        errorDialog.setMessage("Value should be between " + min + " and " + max + " " + units);
        errorDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        errorDialog.show();
      }
    }

    super.onClick(dialog, which);
  }
}
```

The onCreateView and onBindView operations were sometimes causing the PreferenceFragment to stop responding to item clicks although I am not sure why.  It has something to do with the setSummary call because if I comment out those calls in onCreateView and onBindView, everything is selectable.

After looking at some other examples, I modified the class to the following and now it works great:

```
public class NumberWithRangePreference extends EditTextPreference {

  private int min = -1;
  private int max = -1;
  private int defaultValue = -1;
  private int oldValue = -1;
  private String units = "";

  public NumberWithRangePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    for (int i=0; i<attrs.getAttributeCount(); ++i) {
      String attr = attrs.getAttributeName(i);

      if (attr.equals("min")) {
        min = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
      } else if (attr.equals("max")) {
        max = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
      } else if (attr.equals("units")) {
        units = attrs.getAttributeValue(i);
      } else if (attr.equals("defaultValue" )) {
        defaultValue = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
        oldValue = defaultValue;
      }
    }

    oldValue = Integer.parseInt(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getString(getKey(), "" + defaultValue));
    setSummary("" + oldValue + " " + units);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
      int value = Integer.parseInt(getEditText().getEditableText().toString());
      if ((value < min) || (value > max)) {

        getEditText().setText("" + oldValue);

        AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        errorDialog.setTitle("Invalid Entry");
        errorDialog.setMessage("Value should be between " + min + " and " + max + " " + units);
        errorDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        errorDialog.show();
      } else {
        setSummary("" + value + " " + units);
      }
    }

    super.onClick(dialog, which);
  }    
}
```